# Restrict people from sites

Tags: 7

Is there any module that can restrict people from accessing certain pages when they are not logged in?

Answer (score 2):

There's a contrib module, [contentaccess](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) which is fairly easy to use and permissions can be managed on a node by node basis.

There's a good article about Drupal content access control [here](https://drupal.org/node/270000)